# regular expression to extract strings from smarty files

Tags: php, regex, smarty, preg-match

i have a batch of Smarty files that i need to extract strings from, the 2 formats i need to extract from are :

```
format 1 : {lang mkey='some_str'}
format 2 : {lang skey='some_other_str'}
```

i need the output to be :

```
some_str
some_other_str
```

i'm using php, thanks in advance, sorry for the newbie question but i'm very new with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $results = array();
  preg_match_all("/[ms]key='(.+?)'/", $input, $results, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
  echo $results[1]."\n";
?>
```

EDIT: Because apparently sometimes non-greedy matching is needed on the sample data...

Comment: hi again, i ran it through about 100 files and it tripped up in a few cases, example :

{lang mkey='please_be_sure'}&nbsp;<a href="changepwd.php">{lang mkey='change_your_admin_pwd'}

Comment: If that's all on the same line then you'll need to do the following instead to use nongreedy matching.  "/[ms]key='(.+?)'/"